# I wish to prove following equality using Mean Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

I am attempting to prove an equality using Mean Value theorem, which is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\log((1-\tanh^2{(x+y)}))=\log{(1-\tanh^2{(x)})}+\frac{\tanh{\zeta_2}}{\zeta_1}(\tanh^2{(\zeta_2)}-1)y
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $1-\tanh^2{(y)} \leq \zeta_1 \leq 1-\tanh^2{(x)}$ and $x \leq \zeta_2 \leq y$.

I have developed certain part of the proof, however I am not able to prove it entirely. 
This is how I tried to prove it:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^{x+y}(-2\tanh{(v)})dv=\log{(1-\tanh^2{(v)})}|_0^{x+y}=\log{(1-\tanh^2{(x+y)})}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Using integral mean value theorem, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^{x+y}(-2\tanh{(v)})dv=(x+y)(-2\tanh{(\zeta)})
\end{split}
\end{equation},
where $0<\zeta<x+y$.
Please help me get the correct answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that this equality can be proved by the Mean Value Theorem and that your direction of approach is in the right direction? Intuitively, you need to apply the Mean Value Theorem twice where the integrals have the lower and upper bound with$$1-\tanh^2{(y)} \text{ and }1-\tanh^2{(x)} \text{ for }  \zeta_1 $$ and $$x \text{ and } y \text{ for }  \zeta_2 $$

Comment: Yeah that is apparent that, one needs to apply MVT twice, however in what two steps does it require the MVT is unknown. Also, one of the IEEE transactions uses this equality without proving it. I am trying to prove it.